# To merge excel tables with some equals names of columns with python and pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, merge

there are two excel tables:

table1:

```
id  name    color   size
1   shoes   black   42
2   shoes   black   44
3   jacket  brown   44
4   jacket  brown   46
```

table2:

```
name    size    country            host     id
shoes   42      usa      cotton    man  
shoes   44      rus                woman    2
jacket  44      eu                 man  
shoes   46      usa      polieste  woman    
shoes   42      rus                man  
hat     m       eu                 woman
```

need make table3, inserting data with some equals columns, for example (**name** and **size**) or just (**id**) and not include columns with unname columns

like this (for equals **name** and **size**):

```
name    size    country host    id  color
shoes   42      usa     man     1   black
shoes   44      rus     woman   2   black
jacket  44      eu      man     3   brown
shoes   46      usa     woman       
shoes   48      rus     man     
hat     m       eu      woman
```

is it possible in pandas with DataFrame?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for ```merge``` and ```join```. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert `size` column from `table1` to `str` as `size` in `table2` is also a string column:

```
In [40]: table1['size'] = table1['size'].astype(str)
```

Then, you can join them like this:

```
In [44]: table3 = pd.merge(table2, table1, on=['name', 'size'], how='left').drop(['Unnamed: 3', 'id_x'], 1).rename(columns={'id_y': 'id'})                                                                  

In [45]: table3                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[45]: 
     name size country   host   id  color
0   shoes   42     usa    man  1.0  black
1   shoes   44     rus  woman  2.0  black
2  jacket   44      eu    man  3.0  brown
3   shoes   46     usa  woman  NaN    NaN
4   shoes   42     rus    man  1.0  black
5     hat    m      eu  woman  NaN    NaN
```